# How to override the FOSUserBundle's profile controller correctly?

Tags: symfony

I would like to override the ProfileController's edit action of FosUserBundle. I've created the controller in my own UserBundle, copied the edit action into it and made some changes. In this controller there is a check if the logged in user is an instanceOf UserInterFace. Apparently it's not because it throws an access denied exception when I go to /profile/edit

Why isn't the logged in user an instanceOf UserInterFace anymore?

Controller:

```
namespace Tennisconnect\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\ProfileController as BaseController;

class ProfileController extends BaseController
{
/**
     * Edit the user
     */
    public function editAction()
    {
        $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

        if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this     section.');
        }

        $form = $this->container->get('fos_user.profile.form');
        $formHandler = $this->container->get('fos_user.profile.form.handler');

        $process = $formHandler->process($user);
        if ($process) {
            $user->upload();
            $this->setFlash('fos_user_success', 'profile.flash.updated');

            return new RedirectResponse($this->container->get('router')->generate('fos_user_profile_show'));
        }

        return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse(
        'FOSUserBundle:Profile:edit.html.'.$this->container->getParameter('fos_user.template.engine'),
        array('form' => $form->createView(), 'theme' => $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.template.theme'))
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading your code snippet, I would say it's simply because you don't match the full qualified namespace of UserInterface.

Either import the class with:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
```

or modify your code like this:

```
if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof  Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface) {
```

Answer (score 3):

The cleaner solution is to create a new Bundle "MyFOSBundle", in the bundle class :

```
getParent()
{
    return "FosBundle";
}
```

Then you write the file you want override on the same location.

http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html