# Parameter undefined in FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu, web-applications, fosuserbundle

I'm adding new features in a Symfony2 Web Application, and after few development the edit user feature stop working.

For some reason the erro is showed in `edit user screen`, not in `show user`.

The error:

```
The parameter "fos_user.template.theme" must be defined.
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException
```

The `editAction` method:

```
/**
 * Edit the user
 */
public function editAction()
{
    $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
    }

    $form = $this->container->get('fos_user.profile.form');
    $formHandler = $this->container->get('fos_user.profile.form.handler');

    $process = $formHandler->process($user);
    if ($process) {
        $this->setFlash('notice', 'As alterações foram feitas com sucesso.');

        return new RedirectResponse($this->container->get('router')->generate('fos_user_profile_show'));
    }

    return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse(
        'FOSUserBundle:Profile:edit.html.'.$this->container->getParameter('fos_user.template.engine'),
        array('form' => $form->createView(), 'theme' => $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.template.theme'))
    );
}
```

I believe something is missing on config.yml, but I can't add the correct paramter on `fos_user.template.theme`:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: App\UserBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            type: duo_vozi_user_registration
    profile:
        form:
            type: duo_vozi_user_profile
    from_email:
        address:        vozi@vozi.com.br
        sender_name:    VOZI
```

These are the version of used components:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.1.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.0.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.1.*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
    "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "1.3.1",
    "brazilianfriendsofsymfony/sync-content-bundle": "dev-master",
    "brazilianfriendsofsymfony/brasil-bundle":"dev-master",
    "brazilianfriendsofsymfony/settings-management-bundle":"dev-master",
    "brazilianfriendsofsymfony/pagseguro-bundle":"dev-master",
    "brazilianfriendsofsymfony/twig-extensions-bundle":"dev-master",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle":"dev-master",
    "duo/cms-bundle": "v1.1.9"
},
```

Comment: Why did you used the ubuntu tag? Do you use Sonata, there was an [issue with the same error message](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/issues/104)?

Comment: This parameter is missing from [FosUserBundle configuration](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php). So you may be using another bundle, please give us more information.

Comment: @n.1 I used ubuntu tag, because I'm using Ubuntu. And is the same error message, not the same error!

Comment: Yes you use ubuntu by the probability that the bug is due to ubuntu is low. See all the other questions on this site, they are never tagged with the OS the OP uses.

Comment: Please add the *show user* controller's code in your question and see this [other link](https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXMultiUserBundle/issues/4) and [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11902272/2257664). Also, where do the `editAction()` code come from?

Comment: Is there a reason for you to use the [outdated Symfony 2.1](http://symfony.com/roadmap?version=2.1)?

Comment: Yes, Is an old service that we are creating new functions. We made this application in 2011, and now we are upgrading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research to find the origin of your controller's code, it seems that it comes from an old version of FOSUserBundle [(1)](https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXMultiUserBundle/issues/4) [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11902272/2257664) [(3)](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/commit/50ab4d8fdfd324c1e722cb982e685abdc111be0b#diff-d4004c88ffec3de7844561c92965d48a). So I suggest you to upgrade your Symfony2 or use the last version of FOSUserBundle and use the last version of the documentation.

Comment: I have added a `composer.json` piece with the versions of the components. When I made `./composer.phar update` I have some problems...

Answer (score 0):

If you use twig as your template engine, remove all calls to `$this->container->getParameter('fos_user.template.theme')` in your code and replace them with the static string `'twig'`.

This is true since [FOSUserBundle removed the option to switch to a different templating engine](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/commit/f9abc6447053c2aa2c1456b152c522d60291bd85).

@Victor, the `editAction()` method would become :

```
/**
 * Edit the user
 */
public function editAction()
{
    $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
    }

    $form = $this->container->get('fos_user.profile.form');
    $formHandler = $this->container->get('fos_user.profile.form.handler');

    $process = $formHandler->process($user);
    if ($process) {
        $this->setFlash('notice', 'As alterações foram feitas com sucesso.');

        return new RedirectResponse($this->container->get('router')->generate('fos_user_profile_show'));
    }

    return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse(
        'FOSUserBundle:Profile:edit.html.twig',
        array('form' => $form->createView(), 'theme' => $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.template.theme'))
    );
}
```